# How to create Solr schema for hierarchical facet by splitting data into multiple fields at index time

Tags: solr, hierarchical-data, faceted-search

I want to implement Solr hierarchical facet for my application where there is 2 level hierarchy between Category and SubCategory. I want to use a solution mentioned on http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets link.

**The flattened data will be as below:**

```
Doc#1: NonFic > Law
Doc#2: NonFic > Sci
Doc#3: NonFic > Sci > Phys
```

And this data should be split into a separate field for each level of the hierarchy at index time. Same as below.

**Indexed Terms**

```
Doc#1: category_level0: NonFic; category_level1: Law
Doc#2: category_level0: NonFic; category_level1: Sci
Doc#3: category_level0: NonFic; category_level1: Sci, category_level2:Phys
```

So can anyone please suggest ways to implement this? How do I define Solr schema to achieve this? I could not find any reference for splitting data as mentioned above at Index time.

Thanks,

Priyanka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to display those individual fields as part of the documents returned? In which case you need those split values in 'stored' version of the field. If you only need to have them during search or during faceting, you can ignore the 'stored' form and concentrate on 'indexed' form.

In either case, if you need to split one field into several, you can do that with copyField or with UpdateRequestProcessor.

With copyField, the 'stored' form will be the same for all fields, but you can have different processors for each field, picking different part of the hierarchy for the 'indexed' part.

With UpdateRequestProcessor, you can write a custom one that takes one field and then spits out several fields, each with only its part of the path. You can do a custom one or do a couple of field copies and then different Regex processor on each field.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response. Apart from faceting I also want to show list of categories and subcategories on my homepage. I want to populate this list from Solr database only. Is this possible with the approach you are suggesting?

Comment: Well, you have the categories and subcategories in separate fields. I am not sure why you would NOT be able to do so. Sounds reasonably straightforward to me.

Comment: Actually I am pretty new to Solr so needs some direction here. can you please tell me suppose I have document in below format <br /> `Doc#1: NonFic > Law
Doc#2: NonFic > Sci
Doc#3: NonFic > Hist, NonFic > Sci > Phys` <br /> then how do I convert it into `Doc#1: 0/NonFic, 1/NonFic/Law
Doc#2: 0/NonFic, 1/NonFic/Sci
Doc#3: 0/NonFic, 1/NonFic/Hist, 
             0/NonFic, 1/NonFic/Sci, 2/NonFic/Sci/Phys` br /> at index time? Do I have to write custom tokenizer?

Comment: The exact implementation will depend on your exact requirements. Nobody can quite help you all the way. However, I would start by looking at [PaternTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory) and trying to use Java regular expressions to get the parts you want.

Answer (score 0):

To split the data, use a [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) that allows you to transform the data using Javascript within your config files.

Add the following to your **db-data-config** at the same level as dataSource and document. This defines a function that splits the string within a field on the delimiter, >, and adds a field for each of the split values called category_level0, category_level1,...

```
<script><![CDATA[
    function CategoryPieces(row) {
        var pieces = row.get('ColumnToSplit').split('>');
        for (var i=0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            row.put('category_level' + i, pieces[i]);
        }
        return row;
    }
]]></script>
```

Then in your main `<entity>` tag, add `transformer="script:CategoryPieces"`, and add the columns to your field list.

```
<field column="category_level0" name="Category_Level0" />
<field column="category_level1" name="Category_Level1" />
```

Last, in your **schema.xml**, add the new fields.

```
<field name="Category_Level0" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="Category_Level1" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```