# How to use Pivot Faceting? Is there Any tokenizer which support Pivot Facet?

Tags: solr

I want to implement solr hierarchical facet for my application.

My structure is like below:

Doc#1: NonFic > Law Doc#2: NonFic > Sci Doc#3: NonFic > Sci > Phys

So can anyone please suggest ways to implement this? How do I define Solr schema to achieve this?

Is there any tokenizer which support Pivot Facet to generate hierarchical  tree?

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to split the data into a separate field for each level of the hierarchy as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23433856/1152449). Then you can either set the pivot fields in the query as defined in the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets) or you can set the pivot fields as a default in your solrconfig.xml.

For the latter, in your standard requestHandler, under defaults, add the following.

```
<str name="facet">true</str>
<str name="facet.pivot">Category_Level0,Category_Level1</str> <!--Add as many categories as you have separated by commas-->
<int name="facet.pivot.mincount">0</int>
```